# Problema con canvas al subir imagen de forma dinamica. El lienzo se ha visto afectado por datos de origen cruzado en la imagen

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo un problema al momento de cargar una imagen en javascript de forma dinámica, estoy haciendo un proyecto pequeño con una api llamada ocrad.js para leer el texto que esta dentro de una imagen pero no me funciona, ya trate de buscar la solución en stack en ingles pero no se si aplique bien la solución o realmente no funciona, la imagen por cierto es local, no en línea.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- <img src="prueba2.png" alt=""> -->
    <canvas id="canvasImagen" width="319" height="189"></canvas>

    <hr>

    <textarea id="resultado" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

    <!-- <script src="js/main.js"></script> -->
    <script src="js/ocrad.js"></script>

    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
    let imagen = new Image();

    imagen.addEventListener('load',function(){
        let canvasImagen = document.querySelector('#canvasImagen');
        let contexto = canvasImagen.getContext('2d');

        contexto.drawImage(imagen, 0, 0);
        

        let datosImagen = contexto.getImageData(0, 0, this.width, this.height); <!---- Aquí esta la colisión -->


        try{
            let texto = OCRAD(datosImagen);

            document.querySelector('#resultado').innerText = texto;
        } catch(error){
            document.querySelector('#resultado').innerText = "Error: " + error;
        }

        
    });
    imagen.src = './imagenes/prueba2.png';  <!------- Aquí se carga la imagen -->

    // canvasImagen.setAttribute('crossOrigin', ''); <!------- Solución que no funciono en ingles -->
    // canvasImagen.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"; <!------- Solución que no funciono en ingles -->
})
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Imagen del error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: intenta servir tu `index.html` desde un servidor. Te puedes instalar una extensión en tu editor para que te cree un servidor local y que sirve los archivos. Tienes [live-server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) para visual studio code

Comment: ¿Y para sublimeText?.

Comment: pues nosé la verdad